# Isolate the day from the date into Group 1

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a regex which works fine with leading 0s on the date but, I cannot assume to have a leading 0.
The second thing is the day should be in group 1. The API is looking for the day in that group.

Also it's a sticky match

String: 2020.7.12-qui

Case 1:
RegEx https://regexr.com/57cea
(Works with leading 0 but, fails on non leading 0)

```
.*.(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-.*
```

Case 2:
RegEx [regexr.com/57cft](https://regexr.com/57cft)
(Works on non leading 0 but, fails on double digit)

```
.*.(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-.*
```

Comment: Do you want to match the data format and capture the days in group 1? Start with a word boundary and match the - after `\b\d{4}\.\d{1,2}\.(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-` https://regex101.com/r/czVLD3/1 You can make the date more specific, see https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prably just need to escape the dot `.*\.([12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])-.*`
becuase the day is seperaterd by a dot to left and a dash to right.